# Disable showing content while moving features in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

When moving features in edit mode, normally it shows features content (new position of features) in every displacement of mouse cursor as shown in the image.

[image]

In case of small number of features, no problem. But while moving thousands of features, QGIS freezes for a long time before it shows features content. Sometimes I have 10.000-50.000 features (~1.000.000 features in total) that I have to move at the same time.

I need to move features manually. I don't move all features at once, but partially. Using tools slows me down.

How can I disable showing content while moving features?

Comment: Can you use the Vector Geometry -> Translate tool to move the features instead of dragging them?

Comment: @spatialthoughts  I could. But I need to move features manually. I don't move all features at once, but partially. Using tools slows me down.

Comment: I think you can't, maybe using python you can

Comment: I agree with @FranRaga, it doesn't look like you can. I tried turning off Rendering and disabling the current layer while using the Move tool, and in both cases the preview still shows. You're definitely trying to use a manual tool for something that most people would try to automate. It's really not designed to be used the way you're using it. If you would consider a different solution we might be able to help, but I don't think the solution you asked for exists.

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS 2.x there is the "Move" plugin which lets you move selected features without a preview of the moved features.
You just click the origin-point and the destination point and the plugin moves all selected features.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/move/